# XP Mode and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows, single-sign-on

I've got a computer on Windows 7 x64 because its a great OS. Well there are some programs that don't work on it because it is a 64bit OS. So I've setup XP Mode to put apps on.

One application I have works great because it authenticates in the application. However another app I have uses the currently signed on user to authenticate. Currently then in order to launch the application the user will have to re-enter in their username and password. I'm wondering if there is a way to have the XP Mode sign on with the user that is currently signed on to the host. So if I sign on to the Windows 7 computer and start a app that uses XP Mode, it then will login as me without me having to enter in the info.

Credentials can be saved of course, but then when the user changes their password they would have to be knowledgeable enough to change the credentials; I can't count on that. Any ideas? I've scoured the web and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that the user's AD account is not limited to one concurrent login.
2. Open the XP Mode virtual machine and select Tools -> Disable Integration Features.
3. In the running XP Mode virtual machine, open Start -> Run -> sysdm.cpl, rename the computer (I recommend 'Hostname-XP', where 'Hostname' is the name of the physical machine) and then join the XP Mode virtual machine to the domain.
4. In AD Users and Computers, move the virtual machine from the Computers container to the correct Organizational Unit.
5. If the user is supposed to be a local admin, log in with XPMUser (or a domain account with local admin rights), Start -> Run -> control userpasswords2, click Add, specify the user's domain account, and put it in the Administrators group.
6. Have the user log into the XP Mode VM using his/her domain account instead of XPMUser.
7. Map a network drive to the user's home directory, if this didn't happen automatically via Group Policy when the VM was joined to the domain and the user logged in.
8. If the user is not supposed to have local admin privileges, disable the XPMUser account or reset its password.

That should do it.  Keep in mind that XP Mode will require its own antivirus software & license.

Comment: Hmm, well I figured I could do it this way, but my question was really is there a way to have it automatically pull the credentials....

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the XP-Mode to the domain, then login to the XP-Mode with your current credentials.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that once the XPMode has been joined to the domain you update the settings of the VM with relevant credentials it should use to log onto the domain!